# Fatal error on mysqli_stmt_get_result(), nd_mysqli is already installed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

first of all, this is not a duplicate question, I read all similar questions here find that I should check nd_mysqli on the server, I have a shared host server and I contact admin for enabling this driver, he told me that it's already enabled. PHP version is also set to highest available which is 7.2, Also because of the shared host, I can't access php.ini file to make changes. so here's my code for search thing on my website and I use prepared statements for this:

PHP

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php include "./db.php"; ?>
<?php include "./functions.php"; ?>
<?php include "./header.php"; ?>

<nav>
<?php include "./navbar.php"; ?>
</nav>

<section id="main-section">
  <div class="page-title">
    <p>search result</p>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['search'])){
      $search_str = $_POST['search'];
      $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $search_str);
      if(strlen($search) > 0) {
       $per_page = 12;

       if(isset($_GET['page'])){
        $page = $_GET['page'];
       } else {
         $page = 1;
       }
       if($page == "" || $page == 1) {
         $page_1 = 0;
       } else {
         $page_1 = ($page * $per_page) - $per_page;
       }

    $item_count = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE (product_title)  LIKE ? OR (product_cat) LIKE ? OR  (product_brand)  LIKE ? OR (product_info) LIKE ?";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $item_count)) {
      echo "SQL statement failed!";
    } else {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss', $search_str, $search_str, $search_str, $search_str);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
      $count_pages = ceil($count / $per_page) ;
    }


    if($count == 0) {
      echo "<p class='noresult'>no result :(</p>";
    } else {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE (product_title)  LIKE ? OR (product_cat)  LIKE ? OR  (product_brand)  LIKE ? OR (product_info) LIKE ? LIMIT $page_1,$per_page ";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query)) {
      echo "SQL statement failed";
    } else { 
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss', $search_str, $search_str, $search_str, $search_str);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $product_id = $row['product_id'];
      $product_cat = $row['product_cat'];
      $product_title = shorterTitle($row['product_title']);
      $product_brand = $row['product_brand'];
      $product_main_image = $row['product_main_image'];
      $product_size = toPersianNum($row['product_size']);
      $product_colors = $row['product_colors'];
      $product_material = $row['product_material'];
      $product_info = shorterInf($row['product_info']);
      $product_price = intval($row['product_price']);
      $product_dir = str_replace(" ", "_", $product_title);
      ?>
.
.
.
```

this is the error I get when I try to search something:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_stmt_get_result() in /home4/maketir/public_html/Includes/search.php:41 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   /home4/maketir/public_html/Includes/search.php
>   on line
>   41

how can I fix this?

Comment: Is `mysqlnd` installed and enabled? Check with `phpinfo()`

Comment: @Qirel According to what the host admin said yes, it is enabled. and because of shared-hosting I can't access php.ini file also phpinfo();

Comment: You should be able to check what is installed with `phpinfo()` none the less. If you don't have the `mysqlnd` or the `nd_mysqli` (you need both) module installed and enabled, then you can't use `mysqli_stmt::get_result()`.

Comment: @Qirel when I run `phpinfo()` i got this: **Warning: phpinfo() has been disabled for security reasons**

Comment: Ah okay. Well, then your host-admin is either telling you wrong, or he didn't check that you have *both* `mysqlnd` and `nd_mysqli` installed and enabled.

Comment: @Qirel he said because of shared hosting, we cant let you to change some features. anyway if I use only `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function can I prevent SQL injection? I want my website being safe not 100% but a safe level that I feel confident that my database won't attack.

Comment: You can use regular prepared statements, you do not need `get_result()` to do that. See https://php.net/mysqli-stmt.fetch

Comment: @Qirel How can I convert my code to regular statement? `mysqli_stmt_fetch()` returns `boolean` instead of `mysqli_result`. I'm a little new to PHP.

Comment: Correct, you bind the resulting columns into `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()`, and then loop `mysqlI_stnt_fetch()` - there are examples in the manual.